# How can I index a single value from a list containing sublists in python?

Tags: python, list, indexing

As an example, right now I have a list of:

```
list = [[1276, 'c'], [910, 'b'], [819, 'o'], [759, 'z'], [699, 'l']]
```

and I would like to index this list for only a specific letter, for instance:

```
index = list.index('c')
```

As is, I realize that I'm going to get a ValueError, and I've learned that to make this work, I would need to index for the entire sublist.

```
index = list.index([1276,'c'])
```

Is there anyway I can work around having to index for the list as a whole, given that I don't currently know the integer value?

I hope this all makes sense, and if needed, I can certainly provide further clarification.

Thank you

Comment: You could iterate over the list of lists and build a dictionary of *indices* for each item then use the dictionary. [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) might be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the inner lists will only have two values, you could create your own function to get the first item that matches with [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def get_index(lst, item):
    return next((i for i, (_, x) in enumerate(lst) if x == item), None)
```

Which works like this:

```
print(get_index(lst, 'c')) # 0
print(get_index(lst, 'b')) # 1
print(get_index(lst, 'o')) # 2
print(get_index(lst, 'z')) # 3
print(get_index(lst, 'l')) # 4
print(get_index(lst, 'g')) # None
```

And returns `None` if an item was not found.

As suggested in the comments, a nicer solution would be to create a dictionary of index mappings:

```
def get_index(lst, item):
    indices = {x: i for i, (_, x) in enumerate(lst)}
    return indices.get(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly iterating over the items in a list AKA `for i in list`, you can iterate an integer value over the length of the list AKA for i `in range(len(list))`.

Here is an example of how to obtain the index of the correct sublist.

```
list = [[1276, 'c'], [910, 'b'], [819, 'o'], [759, 'z'], [699, 'l']]
for i in range(len(list)):
    if 'c' in list[i]:
        index = i
        break
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need two numbers to identify the *location* of  an item in a list of lists?

Comment: My example only shows how to get the index of the correct sublist yeah. To get the correct index within the sublist, the solution is already provided in the question itself: `index2 = list[i].index('c')`

Comment: @wwii: The index of the character is always `[-1]` or `[1]` within the sublist. So here the main task is just to find the index of the sublist which contains the character always at position -1 or 1

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a class whose instances are "equal" to any value can help.

```
class Any:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

list = [[1276, 'c'], [910, 'b'], [819, 'o'], [759, 'z'], [699, 'l']]
index = list.index([Any(), 'c'])
print(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a list comprehension that only returns the letter part of the tuple.  The index will be the same.

```
index = [c for _,c in list].index('c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookups using dictionaries are often faster, so you can build a dictionary, for example like this:

```
list_dct  = dict([ [y, [i,x,y]] for i, (x, y) in enumerate(mylist)])
#=> {'c': [0, 1276, 'c'], 'b': [1, 910, 'b'], 'o': [2, 819, 'o'], 'z': [3, 759, 'z'], 'l': [4, 699, 'l']}
```

In this way you can access the index as:

```
list_dct['o'][0] #=> 2
```

---

If you can get rid of the index you can simply convert your list to a dict, then access by the letter to get the integer:

```
list_dct = dict([ [y,x] for i, (x, y) in enumerate(mylist)])

list_dct #=> {'c': 1276, 'b': 910, 'o': 819, 'z': 759, 'l': 699}

list_dct['c'] #=> 1276
```

---

Remember that duplicated keys in dictionaries are not allowed.